# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method FlipUntilHead

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class coinFlip extends MovieClip {// class
        var bool:Boolean;
        var num1:Number;
        var counter:int;
        public function coinFlip() {// constructor
            RandomTruth();
            var textF1:TextField = new TextField();
            FlipUntilHead(RandomTruth);             // the error is right here*
            if (bool == false) {
                textF1.text = "tails";
            } else {
                textF1.text = "heads";
            }
            addChild(textF1);
            function RandomTruth() {
                num1 = Math.random();
                //trace(num1);

                if (num1 < 0.5) {
                    bool = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bool = true;
                    return;
                }
            function FlipUntilHead(RandomTruth) {
                while (bool == false) {
                    RandomTruth();
                    counter ++;
                    return
                    }
                //trace(counter);
                }
            }
        }// end of constructor
    }// end of class
}// end of package (program)
```

The program is supposed to "flip" a coin until it lands on heads using Math.random and boolean variables to declare if its "heads" or "tails".

I think it might be a very simple error and I am just dumb (beginner in programming).
The error is:

"1180: Call to a possibly undefined method FlipUntilHead"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You do not have to pass any parameters into your `FlipUntilHead()` function, because that function already calls `RandomTruth()`.

Instead of `function FlipUntilHead(RandomTruth)` use `function FlipUntilHead()`.

Then, instead of

```
RandomTruth();
var textF1:TextField = new TextField();
FlipUntilHead(RandomTruth);
```

use

```
var textF1:TextField = new TextField();
FlipUntilHead();
```

Although the function name indeed existed, the error was being thrown because it didn't understand the way that you were passing `RandomTruth` into it.

**Problem 2:** Also, there should be a `}` just before `function FlipUntilHead(){`, and one less `}` at the end of your program.

**Problem 3:** Finally, the `while` loop within `FlipUntilHead()` is not looping properly, because there is a `return` statement that immediately ends the function at the first loop. Here is the final code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class coinFlip extends MovieClip {
        var bool:Boolean;
        var num1:Number;
        var counter:int;
        public function coinFlip() {
            var textF1:TextField = new TextField();
            FlipUntilHead();            
            if (bool == false) {
                textF1.text = "tails";
            } else {
                textF1.text = "heads";
            }
            addChild(textF1);
            function RandomTruth() {
                num1 = Math.random();
                if (num1 < 0.5) {
                    bool = false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    bool = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            function FlipUntilHead() {
                while (bool == false) {
                    RandomTruth();
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just tried it, and the error is still being thrown at me. Could there be another reason to why it doesn't work? Same error by the way.

Comment: Sorry about that - just found the final issue: make sure that your `FlipUntilHead()` function is *outside* of your `RandomTruth()` function. Updated the answer. And one last thing so that your program function - take the `return` out of `FlipUntilHead()`.